# Jenkins Active Choices Parameter plugin not working when Build Triggers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Active Choices Parameter plugins.

It works well but it doesn't work when triggered by 'Build Triggers' - Build periodically.

When running by 'Build periodically',
I expected the value of SEASON is 'spring' and FRUIT is 'apple'.

I think that the 'SEASON' variable isn't recognized in Groovy script.

What should I check?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is started by Build Triggers:
[image]

This is started by me:
[image]

Comment: I found a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69189334/active-choices-timer-in-jenkins

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/biouno/uno-choice-plugin/#known-limitations,
the parameters are supposed to be handled only by humans, and at the moment do not work when the job is triggered by plug-ins, API or scripts.

So, I did workaround using a default value:

```
try {
    if ( SEASON == "spring" ) {
        return [ "apple" ]
    } else if ( SEASON == "summer" ) {
        return [ "banana" ]
   } else {
        return [ "cherry" ]
    }
} catch (e) {  /* if variable is missing, return the default value */
    return [ "apple" ]
}
```